# SQLAlchemy Foreign Key that can belong to one of several possible Models?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, polymorphic-associations

I have a model `Animals` where the field `locationID` is a foreign key that can either be `Forests.id` or `Zoos.id`. Assume that `Forests.id` and `Zoos.id` are never the same.

**Question:** Is this something that can be done in SqlAlchemy?

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Forests(Base):
    __tablename__       = 'forests'
    id                  = Column(String(16), primary_key=True)

class Zoos(Base):
    __tablename__       = 'zoos'
    id                  = Column(String(16), primary_key=True)

class Animals(Base):
    __tablename__       = 'animals'
    name                = Column(String(16), primary_key=True)
    locationID          = Column(String(16), ForeignKey(Forests.id or Zoos.id)) # something like this...
```

---

**More Details**

Found something similar in an example in Sqlalchemy docs such as

```
class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    type = Column(String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'employee',
        'polymorphic_on':type
    }

class Engineer(Employee):
    __tablename__ = 'engineer'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'), primary_key=True)
    engineer_name = Column(String(30))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'engineer',
    }

class Manager(Employee):
    __tablename__ = 'manager'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'), primary_key=True)
    manager_name = Column(String(30))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'manager',
    }
```

Both `Engineer` and `Manager` have foreign keys in the `employee` table

However what I need is for `Employee` to have foreign key in either the `engineer` or the `manager` table, similar to the code below.

*Code below is just for illustration purposes, it obviously wont work*

```
class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    type = Column(String(50), ForeignKey('Engineer.id') or ForeignKey('Manager.id'))

class Engineer(Employee):
    __tablename__ = 'engineer'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    engineer_name = Column(String(30))

class Manager(Employee):
    __tablename__ = 'manager'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    manager_name = Column(String(30))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this scenario, maybe we need to investigate our model a bit more, a good question to start with could be:

> Do zoos and forests have something in common?

- animals live there
- GPS coordinates
- a name humans use to refer to them

> Are there differences between them?

- zoos usually have entry fees
- zoos have enclosures
- forests have a [type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forest#Types), possibly important for our animal dwellers

From the above, we could conclude that forests and zoos have a common base, since if we strip them down to the basics, they are for our purpose the same thing, e.g. they are a `Dwelling` for our `Animal`.

Building on the example from the docs, we could define this as such:

```
class Dwelling(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dwelling'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    type = Column(String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'dwelling',
        'polymorphic_on':type
    }

class Forest(Dwelling):
    __tablename__ = 'forest'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('dwelling.id'), primary_key=True)
    biome = Column(String(30))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'forest',
    }

class Zoo(Dwelling):
    __tablename__ = 'zoo'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('dwelling.id'), primary_key=True)
    fee = Column(Integer)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'zoo',
    }
```

For our `Animal`, this would then look like this:

```
class Animal(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'animal'
    name = Column(String(16), primary_key=True)
    location = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Dwelling.id))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Am also curious what is `Forest.biome`?

Comment: It appears that when I inserted either `Forest` or `Zoo`, the `dwelling` table was automatically populated... how does this happen?